# Remove empty node elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the best way to identify and remove empty elements from the dom WITHOUT jQuery?

If I have code that looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to get rid of both the empty `<p>` and `<div>`?

I tried this: https://www.sitepoint.com/removing-useless-nodes-from-the-dom/ but for some reason it cleaned out all of the spaces in my spans.

Comment: Do you really want to remove it or just hide it?

Comment: Remove it completely.

Comment: _"What is the best way to get rid of both the empty `<p>` and `<div>`?"_ There is only one element that does not have child nodes at code at Question

Comment: With css, it could be done Using css :empty selector.

Comment: whats wrong in using JQUERY ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera Why is jQuery necessary?

Comment: @RohitasBehera Why append a huge lib for a simple task like that?

Comment: To use or not jQuery is not the main problem here, but yes, what did you have already tried Mr. OP?

Comment: vanilla js codes are too long compared to jquery :imo

Comment: I am working with reactjs which is why I do not want jQuery.

Comment: @RohitasBehera _"vanilla js codes are too long compared to jquery :imo"_ Are you taking into account the jQuery source code necessary to run jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to traverse the DOM and find empty nodes.

In the below example, an empty node is considered as a node which has no text anywhere inside it, regardless of tree depth or whitespaces. A node can also be considered empty only if it has no children.

```js
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT)
var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode
var emptyNodes = []

// test if a node has no text, regardless of whitespaces
var isNodeEmpty = node => !node.textContent.trim()

// find all empty nodes
while(currentNode) {
  isNodeEmpty(currentNode) && emptyNodes.push(currentNode)
  currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()
}

// remove found empty nodes
emptyNodes.forEach(node => node.parentNode.removeChild(node))

// print DOM
console.log(document.body.firstElementChild.outerHTML)
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some content <a></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that while traversing the DOM using TreeWalker, nodes should not be removed because it will mess up the "live" DOM iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build a recursive function checking if an element's `innerHTML` is empty to remove them all :

```
function recursiveCleaner(el){
  if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0;i<el.childNodes.length;i++){
      recursiveCleaner(el.children[i]);
    }
    for(var i=0;i<el.childNodes.length;i++){
      if(el.children[i].innerHTML === "") el.removeChild(el.children[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
https://jsfiddle.net/pzqkkobf/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelectorAll` to get all of the elements of a type and then determine if that element has `innerText`.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.content-wrapper');

var ps = wrapper.querySelectorAll('p');

for (var p = 0; p < ps.length; p++) {
  if (ps[p].innerText === '') {
    wrapper.removeChild(ps[p].parentNode);
  }
}

var divs = wrapper.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var d = 0; d < divs.length; d++) {
  if (divs[d].querySelectorAll('p').length === 0) {
    wrapper.removeChild(divs[d]);
  }
}
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;">
    <p>
      Text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach... But then I manually have to identify all element types that might show up. (I'm working with generated code.) On the other hand it should not be too hard to make it into a loop where I feed it an array of element types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:only-child` pseudo class to select elements which are the only child of a parent element, remove the node, then check if the parent node has `.children`, if not remove the parent node

```js
let nodes = document.querySelector("div")
            .querySelectorAll(":only-child");

nodes.forEach(node => {
  if (!node.childNodes.length) {
    let parent = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    if (!parent.children.length) {
      parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)
    }
  }
});

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could I use the `:empty` pseudo class and make it recursive?

Comment: @Winter Yes, you can use `.querySelectorAll()` with `:empty` pseudo class as parameter to get the `<p></p>` element then check the parent element as demonstrated at Answer at `if (!parent.children.length) {
      parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)
    }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to get it to work recursively, that is if there is an even deeper level of empty nodes, then it will remove all of them. But I can't seem to get it to work. https://jsfiddle.net/hf7d2xkg/

Comment: That is different HTML from original Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can recursively check the `.parentNode`

Comment: Sorry about that.